# how to format removable USB disk

Tags: usb-drive, permanent-delete

I Can't find out how to format my usb stick. Have read some guides but can't find **"Format Device"** anywhere.

Anyone got the same problem? Or have a solution to my problem?

Greatful for all answers.

SOULUTION

Go to Dash and find the program Disk, open it and Right Click on de device you want to format.
Or you can use GParted.

Comment: what filesystem type you like to format it to?

Comment: You're looking for `GParted` perhaps? Plug the device in. Open GParted, select the device from the top right drop down, and unmount the drive, click apply, and then you can format it. Then just plug it back in and it should be recognized again.

Answer (score 0):

To format your usb-drive I recommend using G-parted for error-free and easy formatting. To do so first, go to [GetDeb.net](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/14.04/). and follow the instructions there to add their ppa. It is done so that you get the latest version of G-parted. After this, open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your list, then install G-parted using:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now, you need to launch G-parted.

After launch you will see your device in the list if you have already connected your usb-drive.

[image: 1]

But if you haven't then connect your usb-drive and then GParted > Refresh Devices.

[image: 2]

Now, after your usb-drive is detected, you can format your drive by right-clicking on your device and selecting Format to:

[image: 3]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It turns out there's a bug in `15.10` with `GParted`. It has been confirmed so the OP may need to wait a few days before it is fixed. For status and confirmation on this bug please [visit this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1509729).

Comment: @KGIII - That's why I said to install from GetDeb, as it will install the latest version which doesn't have the same bug.

Comment: True but some don't like to go outside of the main repositories for a variety of reasons which is why I mention it.

Comment: @KGIII - Well that's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

++++++++
You do not need to download or install any other software .
Linux has a utility that is named Disk with [This Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1KBT.jpg)

Plug USB in to your USB port , then open the Disc tool .
On the left side bar you will have your HDD and also your USB , klick on USB and in the menu right you will find in option "More option" the formating option you need. See the picture.
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg6fz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I format my USB stick by this method many times. After plugging in the device in USB port just follow these steps,

1. Go to the dash home. 
   Dash home is where you search your computer and online resources, at the top left corner of your Ubuntu desktop.
2. type 'Startup Disk Creator' and click on it.
3. In the 'Device to use' section, you can see your drive.
4. Click on 'Erase Disk'.